# Conditionally serialise fields in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have two classes : `Player` and `Match`.

`Player` has two fields, `playerId` and `name` while `Match` contains two `Player` objects and `matchId` too.

When I serialise `Player` I do want the id and the name to appear in the JSON, however when I serialise `Match` I get `matchId` and `Player`'s non transient fields and their respective values even though I'd like to only get `Player`'s `ids`.

How do I do this with Gson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Gson's @Expose annotation to only expose that field. You will have to build your Gson object by calling GsonBuilders excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() function.

```java
class Player {

    @Expose
    private final int id;

    //constructor, etc

}
```

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Comment: what's the difference between transient and the @Expose annotation?

Comment: You specifically only want to expose id so it makes sense that instead of adding @Transient/transient modifier to each field you just add @Expose to one that you want to expose.

Comment: @Fares Did that help?